# How to use a gps to generate a map

Tags: ros, gps, xsens, gps-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering, if its possible to use the /odom(obtained from converting lat and longitude from gps) to generate a map.

Am using a Xsens mti_g device.
Using cyphy lab ros driver
Converted the lat and log using gps_common/utm_odometry_node

Regards,
AJ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27848/how-to-use-a-gps-to-generate-a-map/) by [AJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1425/aj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-02-17**:
Were you planning on using any other sensor, or just a map of all the places the GPS went?

**Comment by [AJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1425/aj/) on 2012-02-20**:
thank you for your response Mr David.am also using a Hokuyo Laser Scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no idea how accurate the map will be, but you should be able to use the odom readings to get the required transforms needed for mapping.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1425/aj/) on 2012-02-21**:
i am able to get the odom by using the gps_common utm_odometry_node.. But the value is not stable..